# How to pass a parameter via CMDline in Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, parameter-passing, sys

I have a python script that looks like this:

```
a='{}'
```

From my cmdline i want to be able to pass a parameter for that value in the brackets. So:

```
python- my_script.py Hello World
```

The output would then be:

```
'Hello World'
```

Any ideas or suggestion as to how to pass a parameter on the command line in a python script when running it? I am new to python so any tips would help!

Answer (score 0):

Reference [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm)!

I'm also fairly new to Python so not 100% positive this works but assuming it does, To recreate what your searching for.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print ('Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.')
print ('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))
```

After adding the `Import sys`

Where your `python my_script.py 'Hello World'`

Note that:

`my_script.py` equals `sys.argv[0]`

`'Hello World'` equals `sys.argv[1]`

Therefore setting `a = sys.argv[1]` should work!

To test it try to `print(a)`

Also note that this will not work if your cmdline is
`python my_script.py Hello World`
This will treat Hello and world as two separate arguments.